# How to join two ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, database, join, arraylist, hashmap

I have two objects which contains array of dictionary. Each entry of `HashMap` in Array will have around 40-50 fields. Object 2 `HashMap` might contains different keys but there will be one key common between both objects.

```
object1 = ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>

object2 = ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>
```

Object1 `HashMap` is having few fields
Field1, Field2, Field3, field4...

Object2 `HashMap` is having few fields
Field4, Field5, Field6, field7..

I want to join both object on common field4 and result array should have all fields 1 to 7

Output should be same as sql query.

```
Select * from object1, Object2 where object1.field4 = object2.field4
```

If object1 is having 3 rows and Object2 is having 5 rows then output list will have 15 rows if all keys are matching. matching field4 will not be unique in both objects.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Using Java 8 lambdas, first make cartesian product with flatMap merging two hashmaps into one, then filter the results.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do something like:

```
List<HashMap <String , Object >> listFinal = 
               new ArrayList<HashMap < String , Object >>();
listFinal.addAll(object1);
listFinal.addAll(object2);
```

Here I use the `addAll()` method to add the two lists.

For more information you can refer [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-join-two-lists-in-java/).

Comment: it would be String not string

Comment: Thanks but it will not do join on key. Let's say object1 is Employee and Object2 is Department then there will be key in both hashmap call departmentId. It should join on that key. If object1 having 3 employee and object2 having 2 department then output will have 6 rows.

Comment: @user3258915 Ok. Then you will need to write an if loop and check the keys. And then if it matches your condition add it to the list else don't do anything.

Comment: Coming from .net background, this can be done in one line using Linq. Looking for similar in Java. May be stream API or Google guava.